# How come Erlang version is not being updated on Ubuntu?

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, ubuntu-18.04, erl

I am currrently having trouble upgrading my current version on Erlang running on `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Bionic`

These are the steps i used to upgrade Erlang on my machine:

1. added the repository `deb http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu bionic contrib` to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`
2. installed the GPG key with: `wget http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu/erlang_solutions.asc` and `sudo apt-key add erlang_solutions.asc`
3. installed latest version `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install erlang`

In the logs, I see the latest version 25.2.2 being installed over the current version 22.0.7

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1060 linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1097 linux-headers-5.4.0-1060-aws linux-headers-5.4.0-1097-aws
  linux-image-5.4.0-1060-aws linux-image-5.4.0-1097-aws linux-modules-5.4.0-1060-aws linux-modules-5.4.0-1097-aws
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  erlang-manpages erlang-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  erlang
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 196 not upgraded.
Need to get 17.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 19.5 kB disk space will be freed.
Get:1 http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu bionic/contrib amd64 erlang all 1:25.2.2-2 [17.5 kB]
Fetched 17.5 kB in 1s (22.8 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 261955 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../erlang_1%3a25.2.2-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking erlang (1:25.2.2-2) over (1:22.0.7-1) ...
Setting up erlang (1:25.2.2-2) ...
```

but when i tried to verify the version

```
cat $(dirname $(dirname `which erl`)/$(readlink `which erl`))/../releases/*/OTP_VERSION;
22.0.7
```

and

```
~$ erl
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.4.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:1]
```

Erlang is still running `22.0.7`. Am i missing something here?

Comment: [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com)?  Did you try running erl in a new terminal window?

Comment: What does it say if you run `type erl`?

Comment: @legoscia it returns this 
```$ type erl

erl is /usr/bin/erl```

Comment: @asdf i have tried that as well :(